# Find charges contained in a Stripe payout

Tags: php, stripe-payments, php-7

Given a Stripe Payout (`po_1BRxlK...`), how can I determine which charges are contained in this payout? Right now the balance transactions in the API seems like a complete mess.

I've tried searching for all charges between two payouts, but due to the holding period of charges, there might be a shift of a few dates. How would you recommend to match payouts with charges?

I can see that within the Stripe Dashboard, you can see all transactions in a payout, so I assume it's possible to get the same data somehow via the API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `List all balance history` endpoint to do that:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#balance_history-payout

If you pass the payout id to the `payout` parameter you'll get back the list of all balance transactions aggregated in the payout. It only works with automatic payouts though.

Comment: This will not work for a connected account unfortunately

Comment: @AssafKarmon That's true but not really linked to this specific endpoint. When you want to aim your requests at ressources owned by a connected account you need to add the stripe-account header to your calls https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using Report API and API report type: balance_change_from_activity.itemized.1

For more info refer - https://stripe.com/docs/reports/financial-reports/api

Report Schemas - https://stripe.com/docs/reports/financial-reports/report-schemas

For quick reference - you can view the payout reconciliation from dashboard under Reports section.